Defining a variable once for all (input and currfilebase
I have two files. The main is called main.tex and have:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[realmainfile]{currfile}
\def\mainfilename{\currfilebase}%

\begin{document}
main text: \mainfilename\\
\input{aux.tex}
\end{document}

The second one is the aux.tex:
aux text: \mainfilename
I was expecting that since I define the variable in the first tex, it will take the value "main" forever. But, when I called in the aux.tex, it updates the function so the result is:
main text: main
aux text: aux
And I would like:
main text: main
aux text: main
Can you help me, please?

try \edef\mainfilename{\currfilebase}.

You want
\NewCommandCopy{\mainfilename}{\currfilebase}

Full example (I use \jobname and filecontents* just to make the example self-contained and to avoid clobbering my files).
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-aux}
Some text \mainfilename

Some text \currfilebase
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[realmainfile]{currfile}

\NewCommandCopy{\mainfilename}{\currfilebase}

\begin{document}

main text: \mainfilename

\input{\jobname-aux}

\end{document}


